# Upload a folder to server(mvc spring)

Tags: javascript, java, spring, model-view-controller, file-upload

I try to upload the content of a folder to the server. But I can't do it, so I made an example where you have to select every single file.

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm") FileUploadForm uploadForm,Model map) {}
}
```

and the **jsp-file**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title> - Upload</title>
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //add more file components if Add is clicked
    $('#addFile').click(function() {
        var fileIndex = $('#fileTable tr').children().length;
        $('#fileTable').append(
                '<tr><td>'+
                '   <input type="file" name="files['+ fileIndex +']" />'+
                '</td></tr>');
    });

});
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div align="center" class="jumbotron">
<h1>dd</h1>
<form:form method="post" action="save.html"
        modelAttribute="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>Dateien auswählen zum uploaden</p>

    <input class="btn btn-success" id="addFile" type="button" value="Datei hinzufügen" />
    <table align="center" class="table table-striped" id="fileTable">
        <tr>
            <td><input name="files[0]" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="files[1]" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/><input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form:form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

That works great. I found some examples where I can select multiple files at once(just adding multiple), but couldnt upload them. I got some trouble to get this working. I'm surprised its so "difficult" to do a so "easy" thing. I dont know if I have to change my Controller file or only my jsp file. I hope someone can exaplain me how this works. I'm new so please talk to me like to a little stupid kid.
Greets
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Single file input on form:**

If you need just simply to select multiple files and upload them, you almost did it. You just have declare field in you form model as `List`:

```
public class FileUploadForm {

    private List<MultipartFile> files;

    public List<MultipartFile> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    public void setFiles(List<MultipartFile> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

Now in you controller you can access this list:

```
@Controller
public class FileUploadController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/save", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String save(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm") FileUploadForm uploadForm, Model map) {

        for(MultipartFile file : uploadForm.getFiles()){
            try {
                file.transferTo(new File(targetPath+file.getOriginalFilename()));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

And of cause in your form you have to specify `multiple` attribute of file input:

```
  <form:form method="post" action="/save" modelAttribute="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="files" type="file" multiple=""/>
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form:form>
```

Note, that in this way you should not use array syntax, like `file[]`, in input name.

---

**Multiple file inputs on form.**

Let's consider if you would like to load file, as it shown in your code snippets, when you add new file input for every file. First of all, remove field `List<MultipartFile> files` from model of form. We will get it by another way. Now the controller method will be as follows:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String upload(@ModelAttribute("uploadForm")FileUploadModel uploadForm,
                     @RequestParam("files[]") List<MultipartFile> fileList, ModelMap model) throws IOException {
        for(MultipartFile file : fileList){
           try {
               file.transferTo(new File(targetPath+file.getOriginalFilename()));
           } catch (IOException e) {
               throw new RuntimeException(e);
           }
      }
}
```

As you see, now we declared model of form and list of files separately. Also note, that list has `@RequestParam` with name of form's field. And this name specified with array syntax - `files[]`.

Now, how form should look like:

```
  <form:form method="post" action="/save" modelAttribute="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple=""/>
      <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple=""/>
      <input name="files[]" type="file" multiple=""/>
      <button type="submit">Upload</button>
  </form:form>
```

In this example I added multiple file inputs statically, but you can do it dynamically with javascript, indeed. Pay attention, that you should not specify index of array item in name of input. Just `files[]`, but not `files[0]` or `file[1]`.

By the way, you can receive list of files as parameter of method in case with single file input, as well. Just remove list of files from model and declare it as parameter of controller's method.